# Understanding the how Anki determines what’s considered as “finished studying a deck”

Tags: anki

I’ve recently begun using Anki and was curious as to what’s considered “finishing a deck”. For example, if I have 40 cards in a deck, have I finished studying the deck once I’ve seen all 40 cards? How do I know I’ve seen all 40 cards? Does Anki have some sort of algorithm to inform the user that they’ve adequately finished studying a set, or is that judgement made by our best discretion?

Comment: Have you understood ? Any feedback appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look to [the manual](https://docs.ankiweb.net/#/studying). The deck is "finished" when there is no more cards to see for a given day because you have seen the daily new cards, and reviewed the due cards.

The software decides when you have to review a specific card based on your previous answers with an algorithm. [See that page of the manual.](https://docs.ankiweb.net/#/faqs?id=what-spaced-repetition-algorithm-does-anki-use) When it comes to new cards, you can choose how many new cards you want to learn each day, in the parameters of the deck.